# In a WebClient, can I match the request with the response?

Tags: java, spring, rest, reactive-programming

I'm trying to use the new Reactive classes of Spring to do some load testing on a RESTful endpoing.  I'm still learning these classes so I may be going the wrong direction, so please redirect me to an easier path if you know one...

Here's what I have so far.  This is groovy code:

```
def token="xyz"

WebClient webClient=WebClient
    .builder()
    //Using google for example purposes only
    .baseUrl("http://google.com")
    //In the real code, there's a lot of extra headers like this one..
    .defaultHeaders({ headers ->
      headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"bearer $token")
    })
    .build()

//This is where load is measured
for (int i:1..3) {
  webClient
      .method(HttpMethod.GET)
      .header("x","y")
      .attribute("i",i)
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(String)
      .subscribe {
        body -> 
          println body
          //Is there any way to get the "i" attribute here to determine the request???
      }
}

sleep 30000
println "done"
```

I can see the three requests come back, so it is working.  Now, I want to time the latency between the request and the response for each of the three requests.  If I could get the "i" attribute, each loop could start by storing the current time in a map, and then the subscribe method could use "i" to read the map and compare it to the current time to calculate the delta.

Another option that I am considering is to make a new WebClient for every request, but there will be 1000's of requests and I want to optimize for performance.

Also, I'm not too happy about the needing the sleep statement at the end...

What is the best way to use Reactive classes to load test a RESTful service?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why reinvent the wheel and not use a dedicated tool for load testing, such as [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) ([tutorial](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/23/jmeter-rest-api-testing/)) or [SoapUi](https://www.soapui.org/) ([tutorial](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/concept.html)) (unless it's for fun or learning/experimenting purposes)?

Comment: Unless it has changed recently, JMeter uses one thread per network connection.  From previous experiences with it, a small test server bottoms out at a few hundred threads.  Reactive APIs can do 1000s of requests because each request doesn't need its own thread.  Admittedly, there is also an element of learning Reactive.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just use a large set of WebClient objects.  The request throughput high enough in my case to swamp the server and cause errors not seen at slower request speeds.  There was no need to worry about `attributes`, instead I just created a new variable for each iteration of the loop to store the start timestamp.  See code below:

```
for (int i:1..3) {
  WebClient webClient=WebClient
    .builder()
    //Using google for example purposes only
    .baseUrl("http://google.com")
    //In the real code, there's a lot of extra headers like this one..
    .defaultHeaders({ headers ->
      headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"bearer $token")
    })
    .build()

  //Get timestamp here

  webClient
      .method(HttpMethod.GET)
      .header("x","y")
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(String)
      .subscribe {
        body -> 
          //Get timestamp here and compare with the other timestamp to calculate latency.
      }
}
```